# execute .sql file in cassandra

Tags: sql, cassandra, cqlsh

I want to be able to execute my sql files in cassandra but not sure which command should i use to do it on command promt. I'm using windows 10 but I dont use installer for cassandra. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common misconception, but **the Cassandra Query Language (CQL) is not the same as SQL**.  You will not be able to use keywords like `JOIN`, `OR`, or `GROUP BY` in CQL.  If you really are trying to run a file containing SQL commands, you can stop reading right now because it likely will not work.

On the other hand, if you intend to execute a file of CQL commands on your Cassandra cluster, you can do this with the `-f` flag on the `cqlsh` utility (which is located in the same `bin` directory as the `cassandra` executable).

If I have a `getTop3Users.cql` file that looks like this:

```
use stackoverflow;
SELECT firstname,city FROM users LIMIT 3;
```

I can run those commands on my local node, via a command prompt like this:

```
cqlsh -u username -p password -f getTop3Users.cql 127.0.0.1

 firstname | city
-----------+-----------------
      Rick |          Albany
     Brian | Sheboygan Falls
     Aaron |     Maple Grove

(3 rows)
```